# Rails render as js toggle modal -> unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to toggle a bootstrap 4 modal when an entry got updated successful.

if i do it manually from the chrome console, it does work fine but from within a js.erb template file it just throws the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
$('#mainModal').modal('toggle');
at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:1542)
at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:2194)
at Sizzle.select (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:2621)
at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:846)
at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:2874)
at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:2984)
at jQuery (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:140)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (modals.self-0fa40069f1b470beca9b1545857092a50efaaaab19a5aec03e92b45ce68e788b.js?body=1:25)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:5184)
at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:4992)
```

however - it does actually do what its supposed to do, it closes the modal and does the other stuff (updating the row, showing the flash message) which isnt included in the js.erb file for clearity's sake...

my view instrument.html.erb:

```
<table class="table" id="instruments-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Currency</th>
      <th>P&L</th>
      <th>Stuff</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @instruments.each do |instrument| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= instrument.name %></td>
      <td><%= instrument.description %></td>
      <td><%= currency_to_iso(instrument.currency) %></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to edit_instrument_path(instrument), class: 'my-2', 'data-toggle': 'tooltip', 'data-placement': 'top', title: 'Edit Instrument', data: { modal: true } do %>
          <%= icon('far', 'edit') %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to new_account_instrument_path(instrument: instrument), class: 'my-2', 'data-toggle': 'tooltip', 'data-placement': 'top', title: 'Commissions', data: { modal: true } do %>
          <%= icon('fas', 'coins') %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

my instrument_controller.rb:

```
class InstrumentsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :js

...

  def update
    @instrument = Instrument.find(params[:id])
    if @instrument.update(instrument_params)
      respond_with @instrument do |format|
        format.js { flash.now[:notice] = 'All Good!' }
      end
    else
      respond_modal_with @instrument
    end
  end

...

end
```

my update.js.erb:

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@instrument) %>').replaceWith('<%= j render 'users/dashboard/user_dashboard_instrument_row', instrument: @instrument  %>');
$("#mainModal").modal("toggle");
$("#flash-wrapper").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/flash_message') %>");
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.alert-wrapper, .notice-wrapper').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    })
}, 4500);
```

like stated above, executing `$('#mainModal').modal('toggle');` in the console after the modal was opened closes it without an issue..

the modal itself is done after a great guide at https://jtway.co/5-steps-to-add-remote-modals-to-your-rails-app-8c21213b4d0c

so, i have a modal_responder.rb

```
class ModalResponder < ActionController::Responder
  cattr_accessor :modal_layout
  self.modal_layout = 'modal'

  def render(*args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    if request.xhr?
      options.merge! layout: modal_layout
    end
    controller.render *args, options
  end

  def default_render(*args)
    render(*args)
  end

  def redirect_to(options)
    if request.xhr?
      head :ok, location: controller.url_for(options)
    else
      controller.redirect_to(options)
    end
  end
end
```

and a modified application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  ...

  def respond_modal_with(*args, &blk)
    options = args.extract_options!
    options[:responder] = ModalResponder
    respond_with *args, options, &blk
  end

  ...

end
```

and an edit form (i omit the form itself as its not important for this issue)

```
<%= content_for :title, 'Edit Instrument' %>
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>
```

any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Hello Andreas, welcome to StackOverflow..  I have been reading your code, but I have no clear idea of where you included the modal erb code. I believe the `edit_instrument_path` link is triggering your `update` action, which responds with a modal... I would be interested in seeing the code related to this modal.

Also your understanding of this issues is key to find a solution
Thanks
Fabrizio

Comment: Hi @fabrizio-bertoglio, thank you for taking a look at it.. i've updated the question and included the code for openening the modal, though i am not sure if this adds any more information to the issue... coz, the modal opens fine, its the closing part via js which doesnt really do the trick. does this help? thanks again, Andreas

Comment: added the info that it actually does all things its supposed to do, it just throws the error and moves on..
though, i really like to get rid of the error